# How do I print the value of a register in the "When hit" clause of a breakpoint in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, assembly, visual-studio-debugging

In the Visual Studio 2010 Debugger, there's an option to print a message when a breakpoint is hit. (By right-clicking on the breakpoint and clicking on "When hit".

I'm trying to print the value of the register EAX when the breakpoint is hit, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$EAX, @EAX, {EAX}
```

This page does not seem to mention it either:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7%28VS.80%29.aspx
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help in trying to print this register when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible.  The MSDN docs only mention $TICK and $FILEPOS as other pseudo variables not listed in the dialog.  The obvious @eax doesn't work.  Post feedback to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be undocumented, so I am documenting it here on Stackoverflow, now that I've figured it out by brute-force trying.

This will print out the value of the register EAX, in decimal form.

```
{$EAX}
```

I have not yet figured out how to print it in other forms.

Comment: To get it in hex form, can't you simply cast it: `{(void*)$EAX}`?

Comment: @merlin this value isn't working for me in VS2012 says $EAX isn't defined even when it is in {}

Comment: @Maslow I have not tried with VS2012, only VS2010. It's possible that VS 2012 introduced changes.